# Derivative of $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ w.r.t. x where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ ($x \neq \theta_n$)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find the Hessian of a function. I have already computed the gradient of the function. So, I have to again differentiate it w.r.t. $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to get the hessian, but I am facing a bit difficulty to do that. My gradient is- $\nabla_x f(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$, given $\|x\| \neq \theta_n$.

Please help me to find the hessian. Advance thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, the component function is $$\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots + x_n^2}}$$ Now simply calculate the derivative of this with respect to $x_j$. You have to separate the cases $i=j$ and $i\neq j$. It's ugly, but not difficult.

Comment: I was thinking to solve it using $uv$ rule of differentiation. Can it be done by that way?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by the product rule for a scalar valued and vector valued functions of a vector. Namely that if $a = a(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $\boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{x})$, then 
$$\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}(a\boldsymbol{v})=a\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}\boldsymbol{v}+\boldsymbol{v}\otimes\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}a.$$
If you haven't seen this form of the product rule, prove it using components.

Now in your situation, 
$$\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}\left(\frac{1}{\|{\boldsymbol{x}\|}}\boldsymbol{x}\right)=\frac{1}{\|{\boldsymbol{x}\|}}\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{x}\otimes\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}\left(\frac{1}{\|{\boldsymbol{x}\|}} \right)=\frac{1}{\|{\boldsymbol{x}\|}}\boldsymbol{I}-\frac{1}{\|{\boldsymbol{x}\|^{3}}}\boldsymbol{x}\otimes\boldsymbol{x}.$$

Comment: No, I was not aware of it. Thanks for your insight and for providing such an elegant solution.

Comment: Glad I could help.